# WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist error using ChromeDriver Chrome and user-data-dir

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to access some websites with different accounts, and to avoid logging in every time I am planning to make an user profile for each one. I am hosting my Python app on an Ubuntu server, so I have to run it headless, and I also need the mobile emulation. Here's a sample of what I'm trying to do:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", {"deviceName": "Pixel 2"})
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=account-data/account_3")
chromedriver = "./webdrivers/chrome"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, options=options)

print("START SEARCH")
# Google is an example, but nothing works
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
print("FINISHED")
```

I see `START SEARCH` but never `FINISHED`. When I comment the `user-data-dir` options, however, everything works perfectly. The weird thing is that this happens on an Ubuntu 20 LTS server, but in my Mac it has no issues.

---

While trying to get the versions for this question, out of the blue the version that doesn't work started giving me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "seleniumtest.py", line 12, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13f73144538f15c00b370eda6706),platform=Linux 5.4.0-1009-kvm x86_64)
```

The only thing I've really done before getting this error is deleting all the `/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.*` files but those should only be temporary files and new ones should be created all the time when I don't specify the `user-data-dir` flag.

Comment: Please don't change the question based on which you have received well researched answers. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question. Once you receive canonical answers changing the question can make all the existing answers invalid and may not be useful to future readers. If your requirement have changed feel free to raise a new question. StackOverflow contributors will be happy to help you out. For the time being I have reverted back the question to it's initial state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that I did not put an absolute path in the `user-data-dir`flag.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import os

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
path = os.path.abspath("account-data/account_3")
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=" + path)
# other options...
chromedriver = "./webdrivers/chrome"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, options=options)

# do stuff...
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any major issue in your code block.

However **`chromedriver=2.41.578700`** is pretty *old* and *ancient*.

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v83.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/83.0.4103.39/notes.txt) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 83.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v83.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/83.0.4103.39/notes.txt))
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: Thank you, I have been able to get rid of the second error, but the user-data-dir one still remains. I have updated the question to hopefully give more context.

Comment: @TheSartorsss I'm afraid. _TimeoutException: Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 299.389_ is a completely different error altogether. I will suggest to raise a new question with the new error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of all your code try this, first download chromedriver, and install it. Then put that path into the line below.

Remember, when you execute the script below, a new chrome window will be opened but do not close it.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\\Users\\sonal\\.wdm\\drivers\\chromedriver\\80.0.3987.106\\win32\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

For `Mac` users (M1, M2) cores -

use `seleniarm/standalone-chromium` instead of <s>`selenium/standalone-chrome`</s>